# Code signing certificate validation by Java

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, java, digital-signature, code-signing

Despite several web search, I can’t find an accurate explanation on code signing certificate validation by Java.

I am wondering if the code signing certificate (the “final cert”) must already be in the client Java truststore, or if the client only needs the Root CA (and its chain) in the Java truststore to validate it?

I can’t find Java docs that are really explicit about that, so I need technical details about the code signing certificate validation (where the certificate is fetch from, what is needed), not about the signing process.

Answer (score 1):

If a jar is correctly signed, the verifier (often but not necessarily a network client) needs only the root, and if you use a public CA that root will usually already be there.

Specifically, a [KeyStore privateKeyEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry.html) is supposed to contain the full cert chain (although if the cert is self-signed the chain is only that one cert). When `jarsigner` signs using that privatekey (by alias) it creates a [PKCS#7 SignedData](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5) detached signature, which includes the cert chain. For the case where the keystore can't provide the chain, `jarsigner` since Java7 has `-certchain` option to add them, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html .

To verify a jar signature (or any signature containing a cert chain) Java actually can use *any* cert in the chain found in the local truststore. Since roots exist for the purpose of concentrating trust for all chains under them, it's conventional and easiest to have only roots in the local truststore. And JRE includes a default `cacerts` containing nearly 100 roots for "well-known" public CAs like Verisign and GoDaddy.

`jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs [-keystore if_not_default] test.jar` will show you the cert chain used, and mark the cert(s?) found in the truststore with its alias in parentheses at the right.

Comment: Hi dave_thompson_085, thanks for your response. I still can't understand that code signing is validated like "SSL certificate" because in a "SSL certificate", the certificate is binded with a DNS host. However, a code signing certificate is not binded to one particular code, so the signer could sign any code and as you trust the Root CA, you trust all code signed by this certificate seamlessly : it is a big problem isn't it ?